# An inequality related to the Euler product formula

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can we easily prove that
$$\frac{1}{2}\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} \right) \left(\prod_{p \leq n} \left(1- \frac{1}{p} \right) \right) \le 1,$$ where $p$ is a prime number?

The motivation for this question came from [*Mertens’s third Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#Third_theorem). This result would allow to connect the sieve term $\prod_{p \leq n}\left(1- \frac{1}{p} \right)$ with the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$ and thus the natural logarithm $\ln(n)$ in the probabilistic prime number theory.

Comment: Would you like to show your work?

Comment: @LuckyChouhan Only some numerical considerations :)

Answer (score 3):

The right-hand inequality does have a nice proof: let $S_n$ be the set of all positive integers all of whose prime factors are at most $n$. Then
\begin{align*}
\prod_{p\le n} \biggl( 1-\frac1p \biggr)^{-1} = \prod_{p\le n} \biggl( 1 + \frac1p + \frac1{p^2} + \frac1{p^3} + \cdots \biggr) = \sum_{i\in S_n} \frac1i \ge \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i,
\end{align*}
since $i\le n$ implies $i\in S_n$.